# VueJs property not displaying in template but exists in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Hi guys I have an issue with vueJS.

#### In the created hook I have this :

```js
created() {
      var allDocs = [];
      for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(this.docs)) {
        allDocs.push(value);
      }
      allDocs = allDocs.flat();
      allDocs.forEach((doc)=>{
        var data = {parent:doc.code}
        axios.post('/api/v1/getconnumber', data)
        .then((response)=>{
          doc.datas.conventions = response.data
        });
      });
      this.newDocs = allDocs;
    }
```

#### And the property exists in the data :

[image: Vue dev tools screenshot]

But when I want to display the property in the template it shows nothing, I tired to log the result from the template it gives me `undefined`, I'm sure this is an **async** issue but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please share data property code?

Comment: And template code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems to address here.

The axios call is asynchronous, so at the point the `created` function finishes running the `then` callback will not have been called. The rest of the code will have run, so `newDocs` will have been assigned a value, it's just the `conventions` property that won't have been set.

Then the component renders. At this point `conventions` will be `undefined`, as you've observed. There's not much you can do to avoid this, you'll just need to write your template to handle the data being missing. There are various ways to shuffle the problem around so that it is handled in a different place but ultimately something has to handle it.

Next the axios calls will come back, one by one. As each call completes it will update the `conventions` property for that particular object.

In theory this will trigger the reactivity system and cause the component to re-render. However, for that to happen:

1. The `datas` objects must be reactive.
2. The property `conventions` must already exist within those objects. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats

It is likely that condition 1 is already satisfied. It's not made clear in the question exactly where the properties `docs` and `newDocs` are defined but my guess would be that `docs` is a prop and `newDocs` is a local `data` property. There's a lot of subtle nuance here when it comes to determining whether `datas` will be reactive but if you have `newDocs` declared inside your `data` function then you should be ok. You might get away with it even if you don't have it declared there but I would suggest including it anyway.

```js
data () {
  return {
    newDocs: null
  }
}
```

More likely is that your problem is due to the property `conventions` not existing when `datas` is initially made reactive. The simplest solution here is to use `Vue.set` or `$set`:

```js
this.$set(doc.datas, 'conventions', response.data)
```

By using `$set` you'll not only set the property value but also make it reactive. This will allow it to trigger the template so that you see the new value.

All of that said, it seems a little peculiar to be updating the `conventions` property in this way. It seems likely it is updating an object that is owned by the parent component, which is generally discouraged. Alternative solutions include the use of a computed property or creating a lookup map for the conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with axios calls in a for-loop.
Try to put your assign " this.newDocs = allDocs; " after your requests are finished.

I did it with a watcher on a varible which counted up to the size of my max for-loop count.
Or you can try to put it into "then((response)=>{...}".